# how can i call model from cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

- How can i use where condition in cucumber test?
- I need to test reset password functionality.

Below is my code

```
  Given /^I have successfully requested a password reset "(.*?)" and enter "(.*?)"$/ do |url, username|
    visit url
    fill_in "username", :with => username
    click_button "Request"
    @current_user = User.find_by_username!(username)
    click link("http://localhost:3000/edit/"#{@current_user.token}"/password")
  end
```

but i got an error

```
uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

support/env.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'rspec'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end


Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_selector = :css

module Helpers
  def without_resynchronize
    page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = false
    yield
    page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = true
  end
end

World(Capybara::DSL, Helpers)
```

Comment: You can call rails models from within cucumber step definitions, so I don't know why this isn't working. Must be something about how you've set up cucumber.

Comment: Please post the contents of your support/env.rb file.